# How to get all the choices of a choicefield when using django restframework on the frontend

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I am using django restframework on the backend to create an API. I have a 'Post' model that stores text and also has a field 'privacy_settings'.
When creating a new 'post' object on the frontend, if one of the values is a choicefield, then how can we retrieve all the choices for that field from the backend so the user can select and option?

```
ONLYME = 'ME'
FRIENDS = 'FR'
PUBLIC = 'PU'
POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES = (
(ONLYME, 'Onlyme'),
(FRIENDS, 'Friends'),
(PUBLIC, 'Public'),
)
privacy_setting = models.CharField(
max_length = 2,
choices = POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES,
default = ONLYME
)
```

Comment: What about returning `POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES` ?

Comment: Would I then need to create a totally separate view to just get those choices then? Is there no other way around it?

Comment: I'm not sure which front-end you are using. Apart from that, you might send data to DRF in HTTP POST method, so you could retrieve the choices by using HTTP GET at same end-point

Comment: You can use the [@action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator in an existing viewset to return the choices